# How do I solve “parent directory not found” in libguestfs?

Tags: debian, virtual-machine

I'm encountering a known “parent directory not found” issue with libguestfs on Debian 11, which prevents me from creating virtual machines on a host. I already encountered this issue by the past, and the solution was to run `sudo chmod a+r /boot/vmlinuz-*`. This time, however, it doing so has no effect.

According to the [official documentation of libguestfs](https://libguestfs.org/guestfs-faq.1.html), “this issue is fixed permanently in libguestfs ≥ 1.26.” I'm using for my part libguestfs 1.40.2:

```
$ libguestfs-test-tool
     ************************************************************
     *                    IMPORTANT NOTICE
     *
     * When reporting bugs, include the COMPLETE, UNEDITED
     * output below in your bug report.
     *
     ************************************************************
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
SELinux: sh: 1: getenforce: not found
guestfs_get_append: (null)
guestfs_get_autosync: 1
guestfs_get_backend: direct
guestfs_get_backend_settings: []
guestfs_get_cachedir: /var/tmp
guestfs_get_hv: /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64
guestfs_get_memsize: 768
guestfs_get_network: 0
guestfs_get_path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs
guestfs_get_pgroup: 0
guestfs_get_program: libguestfs-test-tool
guestfs_get_recovery_proc: 1
guestfs_get_smp: 1
guestfs_get_sockdir: /tmp
guestfs_get_tmpdir: /tmp
guestfs_get_trace: 0
guestfs_get_verbose: 1
host_cpu: x86_64
Launching appliance, timeout set to 600 seconds.
libguestfs: launch: program=libguestfs-test-tool
libguestfs: launch: version=1.40.2
libguestfs: launch: backend registered: unix
libguestfs: launch: backend registered: uml
libguestfs: launch: backend registered: libvirt
libguestfs: launch: backend registered: direct
libguestfs: launch: backend=direct
libguestfs: launch: tmpdir=/tmp/libguestfsUXZ0pd
libguestfs: launch: umask=0022
libguestfs: launch: euid=0
libguestfs: begin building supermin appliance
libguestfs: run supermin
libguestfs: command: run: /usr/bin/supermin
libguestfs: command: run: \ --build
libguestfs: command: run: \ --verbose
libguestfs: command: run: \ --if-newer
libguestfs: command: run: \ --lock /var/tmp/.guestfs-0/lock
libguestfs: command: run: \ --copy-kernel
libguestfs: command: run: \ -f ext2
libguestfs: command: run: \ --host-cpu x86_64
libguestfs: command: run: \ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d
libguestfs: command: run: \ -o /var/tmp/.guestfs-0/appliance.d
supermin: version: 5.1.20
supermin: package handler: debian/dpkg
supermin: acquiring lock on /var/tmp/.guestfs-0/lock
supermin: build: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d
supermin: reading the supermin appliance
supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d/base.tar.gz type gzip base image (tar)
supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d/daemon.tar.gz type gzip base image (tar)
supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d/excludefiles type uncompressed excludefiles
supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d/hostfiles type uncompressed hostfiles
supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d/init.tar.gz type gzip base image (tar)
supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d/packages type uncompressed packages
supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d/packages-hfsplus type uncompressed packages
supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d/packages-reiserfs type uncompressed packages
supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d/packages-xfs type uncompressed packages
supermin: build: visiting /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d/udev-rules.tar.gz type gzip base image (tar)
supermin: mapping package names to installed packages
supermin: resolving full list of package dependencies
supermin: build: 218 packages, including dependencies
supermin: build: 9617 files
supermin: build: 4864 files, after matching excludefiles
supermin: build: 4875 files, after adding hostfiles
supermin: build: 4875 files, after removing unreadable files
supermin: build: 4881 files, after munging
supermin: kernel: looking for kernel using environment variables ...
supermin: kernel: looking for kernels in /lib/modules/*/vmlinuz ...
supermin: kernel: looking for kernels in /boot ...
supermin: kernel: kernel version of /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-8-amd64 = 5.10.0-8-amd64 (from content)
supermin: kernel: picked modules path /lib/modules/5.10.0-8-amd64
supermin: kernel: kernel version of /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-16-amd64 = 4.19.0-16-amd64 (from content)
supermin: kernel: picked modules path /lib/modules/4.19.0-16-amd64
supermin: kernel: picked vmlinuz /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-8-amd64
supermin: kernel: kernel_version 5.10.0-8-amd64
supermin: kernel: modpath /lib/modules/5.10.0-8-amd64
supermin: ext2: creating empty ext2 filesystem '/var/tmp/.guestfs-0/appliance.d.yj6r81ku/root'
supermin: ext2: populating from base image
supermin: ext2: copying files from host filesystem
supermin: ext2: copying kernel modules
supermin: *** parent directory not found ***
supermin: When reporting this error:
supermin: please include ALL the debugging information below
supermin: AND tell us what system you are running this on.
     src=/lib/modules/5.10.0-8-amd64
    dest=/lib/modules/5.10.0-8-amd64
 dirname=/lib/modules
basename=5.10.0-8-amd64
supermin: ext2fs_namei: parent directory not found: /lib/modules: File not found by ext2_lookup
supermin: failure: ext2fs_namei: parent directory not found
libguestfs: error: /usr/bin/supermin exited with error status 1, see debug messages above
libguestfs: closing guestfs handle 0x557c4c42b8b0 (state 0)
libguestfs: command: run: rm
libguestfs: command: run: \ -rf /tmp/libguestfsUXZ0pd
```

Some sources recommend running:

```
sudo update-guestfs-appliance
```

However I don't seem to have `update-guestfs-appliance` (getting “command not found” when calling it), nor do I understand how to install it on Debian.

Running `supermin` in verbose mode gives this:

```
$ /usr/bin/supermin --build --verbose -v -v -v --if-newer --lock /var/tmp/.guestfs-0/lock --copy-kernel -f ext2 --host-cpu x86_64 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/guestfs/supermin.d -o /var/tmp/.guestfs-0/appliance.d
supermin: ext2: copying kernel modules
supermin: ext2: copy_file /lib -> /lib
supermin: ext2: copy_file /lib/modules -> /lib/modules
supermin: ext2: copy_file /lib/modules/5.10.0-8-amd64 -> /lib/modules/5.10.0-8-amd64
supermin: *** parent directory not found ***
```

I checked the directory `/lib/modules/5.10.0-8-amd64`: it exists on disk, and is readable (recursively) by everyone.

[One page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/759725) recommends running:

```
sudo dpkg-statoverride --add --update root root 0644 /boot/vmlinuz-$(uname -r)
```

I ran it, and it seems to succeed, as if I re-run it the second time, it tells that an override already exists.

What else can I try?

Comment: `supermin` shows `src=` (source directory) and `dest=` (destination directory) as the SAME directory. That confuses `supermin`. Investigate `supermin`. Start with `locate supermin` will give you a start.

Comment: @waltinator: I don't have `locate`, but `find / -name supermin` gives `/usr/bin/supermin` (the actual executable), a file `/usr/share/lintian/overrides/supermin`, and a directory `/usr/share/doc/supermin`. Is this the output you were expecting?